# CoreAnimation: failed to allocate xxxx bytes

Tags: ios, memory-management, core-animation, core-plot

I am developing an iOS app n which I am using core plot to draw the graphs.
15-16 graphs are getting plotted at a time an they all are needed.
I have a sync button which takes the data from server and draws the graphs accordingly.
Number of graphs can vary on each sync.
Before drawing each chart I am releasing the earlier objects using the code:

```
[smartbarChartView.hostedGraph.axisSet removeFromSuperlayer];
smartbarChartView.hostedGraph.axisSet=nil; 
smartbarChartView.hostedGraph=nil;
smartbarChartView = nil;
```

Still when I sync for 2-3 times, I get the error CoreAnimation: failed to allocate xxxx bytes and application gets stuck.

Tried to resolve the issue for a whole day.

any guidance is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not, the code in your question doesn't release anything.

Comment: Yes.I am using ARC and AFAIK setting the objects to nil should be fine to release them.Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Releasing the hosting view (`smartbarChartView`) will release the graph and all of its component parts including the axes and plots. Make sure that you're not holding onto strong references to the graphs or plots.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not making the graphs properties in my code so no strong reference is been hold on graph. Any idea what is going wrong? Its true that I am plotting 15-16 graphs. Can that be cause of problem?

Comment: It's certainly possible. How large are the graphs? Why do you need that many simultaneously?

Comment: Graphs are of considerable size.But setting all properties to nil should do it. Am I correct? In current implementation all graphs are plotted once so can there be a solution without changing much of my current code?...If possible.

Comment: Do you need to keep the whole graphs around (for resizing or interactivity or whatever) or can you render the graphs to images and  release each graph after rendering it?

Comment: Can you please explain how can we release the graph safely when ARC is on? I have doubt on setting it to nil mechanism.

Comment: That's how ARC works. Are you seeing leaks or other problems?

Comment: Actually,I have a ViewController class of which I am creating objects and ploting the graph on that ViewController.Hence each time a new object is created and in ARC dealloc method is not getting called so I have no place to make them nil.I think that is the problem.Now I am trying by taking global object of the graph  and reloading it for each graph. But this makes the application slower...Can there be a better way to do this?